# Quickest way to mount cloud storage as a local disk via NAS, NFS, etc?

Tags: nfs, google-cloud-platform, cloud, network-attached-storage

I'm low on space on my local machine and need to be able to export a large number of files from a program, these files can only be exported via writes to a mounted filesystem on my local machine. I would like to be able to mount some cloud-based storage (object storage or remote disk) to my local machine that would allow me to simply export to this cloud storage as if it was a locally mounted drive. What is the quickest and easiest way to do this? I'm obviously willing to pay for the storage costs.

I looked into Google Cloud Filestore but I'm having trouble figuring out how to mount it to my local machine.

Answer (score 2):

I ended up using `gcs-fuse` to mount a Google Cloud Storage bucket to my local machine and this worked just fine. The docs can be found here: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gcs-fuse

`brew install gcsfuse`

`mkdir ~/gcs-buckets/my-bucket`

`gcsfuse my-bucket ~/gcs-buckets/my-bucket`

Comment: webdav could be an Option